# Simple harmonic motion phase shift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

If the simple harmonic motion equation, suppose the acceleration comes out to be

$$a=-\omega^2(x-c)$$

then what is the significance of $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's apply a co-ordinate transformation such that $x'=x-c$. Intuitively, this means that we have shifted the x-axis by $c$ units and now the point $x=c$ has become the new origin. Thus the new acceleration,$a'$ will be

$$a'=\frac{\mathrm d^2 x'}{\mathrm d t}=\frac{\mathrm d^2 x}{\mathrm d^2 t} - \frac{\mathrm d^2 c}{\mathrm d^2 t} = \frac{\mathrm d^2 x}{\mathrm d^2 t}=a$$

Since $c$ is a constant so its time derivative (and higher time derivatives) are zero.

Now the equation in the new co-ordinate system is

$$a'=-\omega^2 x'$$

But this is exactly the same as the equation of a standar simple harmonic motion. So in our new system the particle undergoes *normal* SHM. As we already discussed, the origin in this new system is $x=c$ and thus the equilibrium point of the SHM is $x=c$. And there is no change in the angular velocity due to this co-ordinate transformation.

So the equation you've been provided is an equation of shifted SHM, i.e. a simple harmonic motion performed around a equilibrium point which isn't the origin.

Comment: @AmritanshPriyam You can also [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).